# "React Native" error Installing pods failed when Creating project with react native cli

Tags: reactjs, react-native, installation, cocoapods

An error occurred during step 'Downloading template' while creating a project with the react native cli.

I'm definitely downloading cocoapods through 'brew', so I don't know why I get this message. (cocoapods version: 1.14.3)

error message >>

```
error Installing pods failed. This doesn't affect project initialization and you can safely proceed. However, you will need to install pods manually when running iOS, follow additional steps in "Run instructions for iOS" section.
```

capture >>

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yegk3.png)

I deleted and reinstalled cocoapods and created a react-native project through `sudo`. When I created the project through `sudo`, it was created, but all activities within the project required administrative permission.

And I want the result of making the project clean without using sudo..

Comment: What did you do to resolve the problem? I'm facing the same issue but it still not working when I run with sudo